# PHP JSON, get return

Tags: php, html, json

I have a php script that i use to send json to another server, but i need to get the return, but i'm not getting, how can i do this?

The return is a json too.

This code is working, but i'm not getting the return.

The return that i need is like this: {"Online":"true"}

```
$data = array(
    "ServerId"      =>  $data_server[2],
    "ServerPath"    =>  "/home/slsolucoes/MTA/",
    "MaxPlayers"    =>  $data_config[3],
    "Port"          =>  $data_server[3],
    "HttpPort"      =>  $data_server[3]
    );

$options = array(
    "http"      =>  array(
        "method"    =>  "POST",
        "content"   =>  json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES),
        "header"    =>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"."Accept: application/json\r\n"
        )
    );

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($data_server[4], false, $context );
$response = json_decode($result);
echo($response);
```

Comment: What is `$data_server[4]` containing?

Comment: $data_server[4] = IP/Mta/API

it's like = 127.0.0.1/Api/Mta

Comment: Shifted your code to the left, if you don't mind.

Comment: Can you print $data_server[4] before calling file_get_contents and show it's value in the question? Do you get a json when calling it from, browser?

Comment: Yes, i need to get the return of the json that i send from the browser.

This code is working for now, but what is not working is the return, my other server is working normally it's sending the return however the php is not catching.

Comment: Can you put the code `var_dump($data_server[4]);` before `file_get_contents` call and tell us the printed value?

Comment: string(12) "13.77.102.81"

Comment: `var_dump($result);` after calling `file_get_contents`. What does it print?

Comment: Print: bool(false)

Comment: It means that you don't get a response from server. If it works on one server and doesn't work on another, probably it means the permissions issue.

Comment: try `var_dump($http_response_header);` after you run file_get_contents to see what the actual HTTP response from the server is.

Comment: This is my code, nothing less than to start a service that I'm running on a linux machine, when I send json to that server it connects the service but does not return json, the code is working, I just can not get the Return, the code that is running on this machine is returning json, who is not picking the return is php.

Comment: var_dump($http_response_header); the returin is "NULL"

Comment: seems like maybe you didn't get a response. You mentioned your data_server[4] value is just an IP address. Are you sure that you don't need to put "http://" in front of it? You say your remote server is working, but have you verified that it definitely receives the request correctly from the PHP script? E.g. you could use a network sniffing tool to watch the request go out from PHP and check it's correct. Or put some logging on the remote server to check the request is received and has the right content and right response?

Comment: From your description I can't understand if you are saying the remote service receives the request only when you try it without PHP, or if you are saying you are sure it definitely receives the request from the PHP script as well. Because obviously, not receiving a response could be a symptom of not sending a correct request in the first instance.